# Android & Phonegap: error occurs when loading javascript function with loadUrl

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i have problem when trying to load my javascript function from java with Phonegap for Android. Everytime when i call the

```
loadUrl("javascript:myJavascriptFunction()");
```

i always have this error

```
I/System.out( 2822): loadUrl(javascript:myJavascriptFunction())
I/System.out( 2822): url=javascript:myJavascriptFunction() baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
D/PhoneGapLog( 2822): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.1.0.js: Line 920 : JSCallback     Error: Service unavailable.  Stopping callbacks.
```

I can see that my javascript is actually called. But after about 10 seconds, my app quits because of this error:

```
I/System.out( 2822): onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=javascript:myJavascriptFunction()
E/WindowManager( 2822): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.phonegap.plugin.billing.CallbackBillingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405d9860 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager( 2822):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
E/WindowManager( 2822):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
```

Can anyone can explain me where is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer that i get from phonegap google group:

```
 this.ctx.sendJavascript("myJavaScriptFunction");
```

Comment: That did the trick for me as well. You should mark it as a valid answer.

Comment: Is there any documentation as far as device -> webview communication?